# Load testing IdentityServer4 gives Exception: Correlation failed when trying to request signin-oidc route after sing in

Tags: c#, identityserver4, load-testing, webtest

We are moving our application to IdentityServer4 for our application, I’m trying to write a load test using Visual Studio and can run it manually on my local machine through the browser, but when I record a webtest and try to reply it, I’m getting Exception: Correlation Failed Unknown location Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync().

I’m assuming this is because I’m missing the .AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc cookie when making the request to signin-oidc route.  Visual studio extracts the code, id_token, scope, state, and session state when logging in .  Not sure how to debug this cause it works with my browser, it just won’t work when running a webtest through visual studio.  Could this be a proxy issue when doing the recording?

Any advice would be helpful, not finding much info on load testing signing in with Identity Server 4 with Visual Studio Load Testing.

I've tried extracting nonce and state from the initial request to put in the request to sign-oidc, but visual studio already is already extracting the same data from there Hidden fields.

Here is the request that fails, it's on the web server that hosts the signin-oidc

[image]

Response:
[image]

Here is the webtest request

[image]

Its using the values from the previous response from the authorize/callback, I also made sure they were the same values, the only one that wasn't the exact same where the scopes which had a + sign instead of spaces, so I set the encoding to false to make sure they were the same.

[image]

Since the browser is doing the post from the previous request when going in manually, and the webtest isn't doing it from the browser, its just making a post request, that could be messing something up?

When I go through fiddler manually, that request has the following cookie that the webtest doesn't have:

[image]

That's prob why the webserver is throwing the error, but I'm not sure where that cookie gets set and if you can even do it through a webtest.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? In Visual Studio? In the server? As text in a HTTP response? Somewhere else? I think you need to provide a lot more details of the request(s) you are sending and of the failing request.

Comment: Visual Studio replays the recorded requests and while the recorder finds (i.e. correlates) some dynamic data it does not find them all. Web test development commonly means finding and correlating other values.

Comment: I updated with some more information on the requst/response that fails.  Fails on the web server.  The webtest is extracting the hidden input types of the previous request which is connect/authorize/callback from the identity server.

Comment: I doubt if the *" webtest is extracting the hidden input types of the previous request"*, rather I suspect that they are the values that were recorded. As per my previous comment, you need to find the correct values in the earlier responses, extract them into context parameters (CPs) and use those CPs in the request that fails. Perhaps you should do some research on how to develop web tests and how to handle dynamic data.

Comment: I added the request showing it's using {{Hidden}} params that the following response supplied. I've done plenty of extracting dynamic data when it's needed, however visual studio is taking care of this which I verified.

Comment: @NickNovotny the cookie is an internal of oidcHandler. it persists the `AuthenticationProperties`. you can grab [this implementation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/75b1a660c3cab2580112e6e0288f3f6bed8189f9/src/Infrastructure/DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.cs) load it into DI together with [DistributedMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and probably you are done

Comment: @d_f Not sure how to do this within a webtest.
I had another approach of creating another client in identity using client credentials, and having a pre webtest plug in to get the token.  This will work except some of the api’s need claims from signing in.  Is there a way to mock the claims when I request a token?

Comment: mock the claims? do you mean "issue a token with some predefined claims"? you can mock a service supplying your identityserver with the data for the token. or you can inject your custom [CustomTokenRequestValidator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/75b1a660c3cab2580112e6e0288f3f6bed8189f9/src/Validation/DefaultCustomTokenRequestValidator.cs) and put in any claims there. but for me it should be simpler to solve the correlation error: if it has a problem with a cookie, just change it to anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get to the .AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc and .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookies from the response of the first request

[image]

I had to add a custom extraction rule to get these cookies from the header and save them the context (to use in the singin-oidc request).
Then on the request to signin-oidc I made a webtest plug in and added PreRequest method to add the cookies from the context that was extracted from the first request.

After doing this I didn’t get the error for correlation on identity, and the right cookies are set from the response, and when I called to get an access token using a refresh token, I was able to get the token to set it to the bearer token to make calls to other apis.

I feel like I shouldn’t need to extract cookies from the first response if the header is setting them, however since it is a 302 redirect, there are dependent requests that also are setting cookies.

[image]

I don’t know if this is overriding the ones set from the previous request (the ones I need, like nonce and correlation).  I also had to take off follow dependent requests and extract the Location Header from the 302 from the first request and manually make the next request.

If anyone else is writing a webtest to log into IdentityServer4 and found a different solution please let me know.

Comment: In my experience, Visual Studio has handled cookies without any problems. However it may be that Identity Server does things that Visual Studio does not expect. Well done on finding the solution and thank you for documenting it here.